# How to make beforeskip and afterskip of chapters different from those of starred chapters in KOMA-Script's scrreprt?

Tags: chapters, koma-script, starred-version, scrreprt

I want to make chapters and starred chapters to have different `beforeskip` and `afterskip`. In other words, my abstract and bibliography shall have more `beforeskip` (about `1\baselineskip`} than numbered chapters do, making the first line of the paragraph in each of those chapters align.

I have used `\RedeclareSectionCommand[options]{chapter}`. Is there any `{chapter*}` or something like that in `\RedeclareSectionCommand` in KOMA-Script? Or any workaround to achieve above?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,chapterprefix=true,headings=twolinechapter,
bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tinos}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
location  = {Reading, Mass.},
year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=2\baselineskip
]{chapter} %% Can I make starred chapter to have
%% different skips using \RedeclareSectionCommand???

\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\large}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\large}

% Make uppercase the chapterprefix.
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
\MakeUppercase{#2#3}
}

\parindent=2em
\setlength\bibhang{1.5em}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
This is the paragraph with citation \autocite{test1}. \lipsum[1]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho what you actually want is a "phantom" chapter prefix.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,chapterprefix=true,headings=twolinechapter,
bibliography=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=0pt,
afterskip=2\baselineskip
]{chapter} %% Can I make starred chapter to have
%% different skips using \RedeclareSectionCommand???

\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\centering}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\large}
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\large}



\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3] {%
 \ifstrempty{#2}
 {%
  {\usekomafont{#1prefix}{\strut%
                  \setlength{\@tempskipa}{\csname scr@#1@innerskip\endcsname}%
                  \chapterheadmidvskip}}%
 }
 {%
  \MakeUppercase{#2}%
 }%
 \MakeUppercase{#3}}%

\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
This is the paragraph with citation  \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you would use KOMA-Script's `\IfArgIsEmpty` instead of `\ifstrempty`, you wouldn't need `etoolbox`. Only a can not a must.

Comment: Exactly what I need. The phantom does work. I do not mind another package, but how would the code be like using \IfArgIsEmpty as suggested by @Schweinebacke ?? The community will benefit from that (I think).

Comment: You are loading etoolbox anyway (through biblatex). If you want to use the KOMA-command you can simply replace the \ifstrempty. I normally use either `\ifstrempty` or `\tl_if_empty:nTF` from expl3,